# Rstudio cannot correctly process comment with Chinese character

Tags: r, rstudio

My system is windowns 10,R 3.5.1,with Rstudio  1.1.463
Rstudio default text encoding is `UTF-8`.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(haven)#读取spss
```

Output of above script in Rstudio is:

```
> library(RMySQL)

> library(haven)#
Warning message:
In readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '~/.active-rstudio-document'
```

Everything is ok when run above script in R.
It seemed **Rstudio cannot read the Chinese in comment** then cause error.

Then I googled, try to figure out whether it's `locale` problem:

```
Sys.getlocale()
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
#library(RMySQL)
#library(haven)#读取spss
```

Get output as below:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document', encoding = 'UTF-8', echo=TRUE)

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"

> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] ""

> #library(RMySQL)
> #library(haven)#
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '~/.active-rstudio-document'
2: In Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

Based on  the output, I found 2 problems:
1.Even `#library(haven)#读取spss`,still cause error in Rstudio.
2.I cannot change locale `English_United States.1252`

How to solve this Rstudio problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Took me forever to put the Sys.setlocale + SET NAMES gbk solution together which is what ended up working.

```
    
library(RMySQL)
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chinese")

sqlQuery <- function (query) {
  
  # creating DB connection object with RMysql package
  DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                         user='',
                         password='',
                         client.flag=CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS,
                         dbname='',
                         host='',
                         port=)
  
  # close db connection after function call exits
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(DB))
  
  
  dbSendQuery(DB,"SET NAMES gbk")
  
  # send Query to btain result set
  rs <- dbSendQuery(DB, query)
  
  # get elements from result sets and convert to dataframe
  result <- fetch(rs, -1)
  
  # return the dataframe
  return(result)
}
 

data <- sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME")
```